# Avoid null returned from background async request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I have a very large request that takes 15 seconds to return the data. I am wanting to call that request when user logs in to reduce the time it takes when they go to the route where that data is loaded (they could get there after it has completed which would show them data instantly, or it might not have completed, but only make them wait a few seconds at that point).

So when the user logs in and gets success I make request for the large dataset:

```
this.getDataService.getAsyncData(data.LinkToken); // This loads request from data service
```

Then I save that data into local storage when it is returned which is then available to retrieve when the user lands on the route that makes that request from ngOnOnit()

```
getAsyncData(linkToken){ //this is background request that is loading while user navigates through app
   this.httpC.get(this.baseUrl + "/AccountInfo/Data?linkToken=" + linkToken + "&deliveryTypeId=" + 0 + "&pickupLocationId=" + 0 + "&paymentTypeId=" + 0).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
       this.asycCollection = res;
       this.globalService.setData(this.asycCollection) //This passes this data to service that stores in local storage
       console.log(this.asycCollection);
    })
}
```

Then that data can be returned as a promise request from the component loaded when that route loads

```
//This sets local storage with the data
setData(refillObject:any){ 
    this.refillObj = refillObject;
    window.localStorage.setItem("refillData", JSON.stringify(this.refillObj))
}
//This gets promise of that background async call
getData(){
    let refillInformation:any = window.localStorage.getItem("refillData");

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => resolve(refillInformation));
}
```

Then from my route component I want to retrieve this data BUT ONLY when it has finished loading the data, otherwise it comes back null and of course nothing works. So, if the user quickly navigates to this page, then it returns null (as the request has not finished loading data) and blows up, but if the user comes back after the request has finished, it all works as designed.

How can I wait and get data when it has finished loading? Keep in mind that this was a background async request from when the user logged in that I'm retrieving from local storage and not making a new request to the REST Svc.

Component Code:

```
getAsyncRefills(success){
    this.globalService.getData().then(data => { //everything below this blows up if the page is loaded before the data request has finished loading to local storage.
        this.orderData = JSON.parse(data);
this.currentDeliveryType = this.orderData.DeliveryTypes.find((item) => 
item.DeliveryTypeId == this.orderData.DeliveryTypeId);
        this.currentPaymentArr = this.currentDeliveryType.PaymentTypes;
        this.currentPickupLocations = this.currentDeliveryType.PickupLocations;


        this.setOptions();
        this.buildOrders();

    })

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use localStorage? And also why you use Observables AND Promises in one app? I'm assuming the slow async request - and the code that later needs that data from LocalStorage is the same application correct?

Comment: I tried using observable or promise alone but it was still loading null value so I added local storage before just to ensure that I could eventually get the object, but this is by no means a finished idea.v they are all indeed in the same app. I am currently looking into using EventEmitter to subscribe to event in service that emits retrieved data when it returns, stumbling the a bit too (subscribe to the emitted value not invoking function when data returns). If you have a suggestion I'm happy to run with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem in the following way.

I would build a **service** that has the responsibility to

- fires the execution of the heavy query on the back end
- expose as a public property an **Observable** that emits when the result of the query has arrived

  - once the data arrive from the back end, it emits the data using the **Observable** exposed as public property

This **service** is injected, via Dependency Injection, into the component that performs the login and the component that needs to show the data.

The component that does the login, once the login is successful, calls the method of the **service** that fires the query.

The component that needs to show the data can use the **Observable** exposed as public property by the **service** to show the data once they have arrived. There are several ways to do this. You can use the ***async*** pipe from Angular which allows you to reference the **Observable** directly in the template, or you can subscribe to the **Observable** and then use the function defined in the subscription logic to fill the required variables.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I wouldn't use local storage but would use a service (sorry don't have an IDE so code may not be perfect).

```
@Injectable()
export class ExpensiveDataStore {

  private expensiveData_: ConnectableObservable<ExpensiveThing>;
  private connection: Subscription;

  get expensiveData(): Observable<ExpensiveThing> {
    if(!this.expensiveData_) {
      throw Error('Must initialize store first!');
    }
    return this.expensiveData_;
  }

  initialize() {
    this.expensiveData_ = this.goFetchExpensiveData().publishLast();
    this.connection = this.expensiveData.connect();
  }

  void reset() {
    this.connection.unsubscribe();
    this.connection = this.expensiveData.connect();
  }

}
```

In your `app.component.ts` or some high level component you can call `initialize()`.  In your component that needs the data you can just subscribe to `expensiveData`.